# SELECT COUNT returns 0

Tags: sql

There is table `Departments`

```
CREATE TABLE Departments
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name  nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    parentDepId int
);
```

[image]

I need to count the rows where `parentDepId = NULL`, but my query returns zero every time.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as DepartmentsCount
from Departments
WHERE parentDepId = NULL;
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: change the where clause to  WHERE parentDepId is NULL

Comment: Should return syntax error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS DepartmentsCount FROM Departments 
 WHERE parentDepId IS NULL
```

That is the only way to compare to NULL (other operators do not work).

Comment: It wont work id will exclude null values even though you use is null in where

Comment: `id` is the primary key and cannot be null

Comment: ok sorry I thougt it is parentDepId thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(Isnull(id,1)) AS DepartmentsCount
 FROM Departments 
 WHERE parentDepId IS NULL
```

Comment: ISNULL is product specific, and no dbms is specified...

Comment: Also, `id` is the primary key, and cannot be null anyway.

Comment: yes I agree with you guys, no need of Isnull function here only if it is primary key

Answer (score 1):

I use syntax `where Column is null`. Comparison with equals sign seems wrong